# css - two divs the same line - scroll body

Tags: html, css

This is what I need,left side menu is 240px wide, remaining width must be filled with second div, whole body should scroll-able, please help ?

```
+------------+-------------------------------------+
|            |                                     |
|            |                                     |
|  240px     |          remaining width            |
|            |                                     |
|            |                                     |
+------------+-------------------------------------+



<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: "Second div should not collapse as browser-resize". How is it possible that it's "remaining width" but "doesn't collapse"? In any event, let's see your research and attempts.

Comment: Soooooo many of these questions, try doing a little bit of research please

Comment: @Santi Sorry my fault,question edited

Comment: This is readily documented online. Please search for it. You might consider checking out bootstrap.

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr Regardless, your question is likely going to be received very negatively. You've shown no attempt to solve this on your own, and the question you're asking is quite common. Consider doing some research before asking.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3):

#### OPTION 1

- use `flexbox`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

section div {
  border: 1px solid red
}

section div:first-of-type {
  flex: 0 240px;
}

section div:last-of-type {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</section>
```

#### OPTION 2

- use `calc()`

```css
section {
  font-size: 0
}

section div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

section div:first-of-type {
  width: 240px
}

section div:last-of-type {
  width: calc(100% - 240px)
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</section>
```

#### OPTION 3

- use `display:table`

```css
section {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%
}

section div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red
}

section div:first-of-type {
  width: 240px;
}

section div:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</section>
```